# how to update elastix openfire to 3.8.2 version

Tags: openfire, elastix

I have install Elastix 2.4.0 and i want to update openfire version to 3.8.2. First i just download the rmp and make the update

rpm -Uvf

it works but nothing appear in elastix administration.

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

To update Openfire you must download rpm package and run following command:

```
rpm -Uvf openfire-3.9.3-1.i386.rpm
```

After update up to 3.9.3 sometimes(on 64bit systems) you need install mo libraries to start java.

Try it with the following command:

```
yum install glibc.i686
```

After that start openfire service from elastix web panel.

Answer (score 1):

You are dear Alexey,

a simple way is to login webshell as root, then type:

```
# wget http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloadServlet?filename=openfire/openfire-3.9.3-1.i386.rpm

# rpm -Uvf openfire-3.9.3-1.i386.rpm
```

if you use a 64bits system, please Java will need some additional libreries, install them by typing

```
# yum install glibc.i686

# reboot
```

After reboot your Elastix Flavour, start openfire service from elastix web panel, this may redirect your web link to `http://yourip.address:9090`

replace this IP by yours.

in that case, logout from Elastix GUI and login again..

Then Find your Openfire Server web GUI into Elastix Web configurator.

Happy hacking

CokoTracy